# Find controls that break the flow in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

When add some controls to a `FlowLayoutPanel`, Is there any way to find which controls cause to the flow break in a new line?

```
for(i=0;i!=100;i++){
  var userControl = new MyUserControl();
  myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(userControl);
}
```

These 100 `userControls` arranged in 20 rows and 5 columns, so the 1st, 5th, 15th, .., 100th user control cause the `myFlowLayoutPanel` breaks in new lines.
I a'm looking for a way to detect these controls.

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk: I updated the post.

Comment: Why not simply iterate controls in order and compare `Top`?

Comment: @Amit: When I resize parent form, the controls arrange in different ways, so the 20 X 5 is not fixed.

Comment: So you want to know when they move, or which are the ones causing a new line? (If the latter, I still don't see the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no method or property which would provide you this information, but you could calculate it manually:

```
Control prevControl = null;
foreach (Control control in myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls)
{
     if (prevControl == null || prevControl.Left > control.Left)
     {          
          // line break
     }
     prevControl = control;
}
```